# How to solve AWS Amplify error: CustomerError Framework Web not supported

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I have an AWS Amplify application (next.js, node v16.18.1) with two builds (dev & prod branch). One week ago the prod build failed with the following error message without any code being modified:

`!!!  CustomerError Framework Web not supported`

The dev build still works. To check I've created a branch from dev called test and ran a build. This build failed with the same error as above.

There a no warnings or such in the AWS Amplify build log.

I've deleted the AWS Amplify app, created a new one resulting in the same error. I've deleted individual builds in the AWS Amplify app all resulting in the same error for the prod or test branch (which is a clone of the dev branch) while dev is building successfully in all scenarios.

Answer (score 10):

It appears the branch is mistakenly being detected as **web** which is what is used for applications that use frameworks like **React** or **Angular**. Try running this command to update your branch's framework to Next.js - SSR:

```
aws amplify update-branch --app-id <value> --branch-name <value> --framework 'Next.js - SSR'
```

[Source](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3168)